# How to set the colors in glowing effect of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-graphics

We can typically set `fontColor` of a UILabel by:

```
label.textColor = self.someTextColor;
```

and the shadow (glow) by:

```
label.layer.shadowColor = self.someGlowColor;
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
label.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

It'ok for simple shadow. However, how can I set the font color with some fancy glowing effect? For example:

[image]

Provided `A` is the color at center, `B` is color at font boundary, and `C` the glow effect. How can I use iOS API to achieve the effect as shown in the diagram?

Comment: Image you have uploaded is zoomed one . Can you help in sharing the image without zoom to get feel of image .