# How to create a glowing effect with a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

I'm trying to achieve something exactly like this:

[image]

I've found a few questions related to mine:

1. [How to set the colors in glowing effect of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875584/how-to-set-the-colors-in-glowing-effect-of-a-uilabel)
2. [IPhone Text Glow Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420131/iphone-text-glow-effect)
3. [Create glowing text effect on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253713/create-glowing-text-effect-on-ios)
4. [xcode UILabel text add outer glow effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015974/xcode-uilabel-text-add-outer-glow-effect)

The majority of the answers suggests modifying the `UILabel's` **layer** property by adjusting its shadow, and the questions are outdated.

I've tried the suggestions using the following code:

```
myLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
myLabel.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
myLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
myLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
myLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

And got the following result:

[image]

The glow is not strong enough and doesn't disperse out more. I've tried playing around with offset, radius, and opacity but the glow was either the same or less distinct.

Is this still possible or is there a work-around that someone can suggest to me?

Thanks

Comment: try changing the shadowColor to white or some other bright colors

Comment: [This](https://github.com/KrisYu/GlowLabel) might be useful to your case.

Answer (score 3):

Change the shadow color to white:

```swift
myLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Comment: From my experience this does not work. Shadow comes out dark looking - not like Pangu's desired image.